# modrewrite is rewriting url saved in php string

Tags: php, .htaccess, external

I'm not sure what's causing this issue as I'm hardly experienced with php and modrewrite.

I'm trying to write a simple page that has a form.  The inputs from the form are automatically formatted and arranged into the standard html email signature for the company I work for.

One of the inputs on the form is a url to an individuals LinkedIn page. I'm currently testing this page on a personal server and domain.  I'll refer to my personal domain as mydomain.  When a user hits the submit button, the resulting link to their linkedin page should show "externaldomain" but it is showing "mydomain/externaldomain"

Edit:

So, before the form I have

```
$jhvar = $_POST["jhvar"];
```

The code for the form itself is

```
<input type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" name="jhvar">
```

And for the output I have

```
<a href="'.$jhvar.'">
```

but the resulting link still shows "mydomain/externaldomain"

I was thinking that the site is in a subdirectory of a wordpress install so maybe wordpress' htaccess file was messing with this one.  Is there something I could put in this page's htaccess file to prevent this from happening?

Weird thing is that if I:

```
echo $jhvar;
```

the link is correct

Edit2:

I figured it out!

I changed

```
<a href="'.$jhvar.'">
```

to

```
<a href="http://'.$jhvar.'">
```

thanks! I'll answer the question once 8 hours passes

Comment: Show us some code (**php** and **.htaccess** rewrite rules - since you mention mod_rewrite, but it is impossible to say how you use it form your description). What handles form submission? Where do you see wrong links?

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor explanation.

Comment: the php code is

    $jhvar = $_POST["jhvar"];

the form is

<input type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" name="jhvar">

and the output is

<a href="'.$jhvar.'">


The htaccess stuff is in a parent directory wordpress install.  Maybe there's something I can put in the subdirectory to prevent it from rewriting?

Comment: If you have something to add to the original post (especially code), edit your question and add it there. If it's in the comments, it likely won't be seen and definitely won't be understood.